# $R$ UFD and integral domain $\Rightarrow$ every $a\neq 0 \in R\setminus R^\times$ is a product of prime elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

Let $a$ be as in title. Then by definition of UFD we have unique factorisation
$$a=\epsilon p_1\dots p_n \quad : \epsilon\in R^\times \text{ and } p_i \in R \text{ irreducible}.$$
It is known that in an UFD irreducible elements are prime. To finish the proof we have to argue $\epsilon = 1$, but why is that?

Comment: You needn’t prove that $\epsilon=1$, rather that you can choose a decomposition, $\epsilon=1$. For this, replace $(p_1, \ldots, p_n)$ with $(\epsilon p_1, p_2, \ldots p_n)$.

Comment: @Mindlack Oh I see, $\epsilon p_1$ is irreducible ergo prime. Thanks!